# Using the `set` datatype in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I just came across a requirement of labeling a user as 1 of 3 different roles. Normally I have used an id, but the roles don't really relate to each other at all.

I had a look at the set datatype, and I added the 3 different options.

- Will the database internally just store the index of the set, e.g. if the set is `set('a', 'b', 'c')` and I choose `a`, will it store `a` or the index `0`?
- I haven't seen this datatype used before when looking at other people's databases. Is it bad practice? Is using an id (perhaps `role_id` which maps to a table `roles`) a better idea?

Thanks

Comment: They're roles - that's how they relate to one another

Comment: @OMG Ponies Please post as an answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're roles - that's how they relate to one another.